# ASP MVC Routing of sub resources

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've notice that StackOverflow use this url:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/123123/revisions
```

How can I add such routing to ASP MVC (3 or 4)?
What if I wanted to add the number of the revision like so:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/123123/revisions/2
```

which translate to

- Controller=posts
- PostID=123123
- SubController=revisions
- RevisionID=2

My problem is that I have to set the entier routing in advanced.
If I'll be able to set routing of posts and add routing between a specific post resource to sub-resource called revisions I'll be able too add /revision after any route that return post resource.

Thank you,
Ido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a route is easy to define at the start:

```
{controller}/{postId}/{action}/{revisionID}
```

But it is highly likely to match too much. This can be alleviated in two ways:

- Use constraints to limit `postId` and `revision` to positive integers (eg. regex `\d+`).
- Hard code the name of `controller` and `action`:

  ```
  posts/{postId}/revision/{revisionID}
  ```

  and thus allow this route to be placed early in the list of routes while only matching the very
  specific URL format.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure I've understood you, but I think this is what you're trying to do.  This will enable you to handle a normal *Posts* URL route, with an optional *Revisions* route appended.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "RevisionsRoute",                               // Route name
    "posts/{PostID}/{SubController}/{RevisionID}",  // URL with parameters
    new { 
       controller = "posts", 
       action = "Index", 
       SubController = UrlParameter.Optional, 
       RevisionID = UrlParameter.Optional  
    }                                               // Parameter defaults
);
```

Then in the controller action for this route, check whether any *SubController* or *RevisionID* parameters are present.

```
public ActionResult Index(string SubController = null, int RevisionID = -1)
{
    if (SubController != null)
    {
        if (SubController == "revisions")
        {
            // handle revisions route
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // handle normal posts route
    }
}
```

This way the user can get a post in the normal way:

```
/posts/1
```

Or a revision in the way you want:

```
/posts/1/revisions/2
```